# Disable rows in ag-grid when columns are set to editable true

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I have a requirement of developing spreadsheet like application using ag-grid. In that I need to disable few rows (not allow users to edit few rows). Can someone guide me how to make specific rows read only when all the columns are set editable to true mode in ag-grid. Or is there any other way to archive this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What will work best is to use the `cellEditor` somehow. It provides row nodes in it's init params that you can iterate through and check if it is a row you want editable or not. If it is not then call stopEditing.

Sorry this doesn't have a working example yet, but that is how I will try tackling it and try to provide a working example when I get one going.

Comment: Thank you Jarod, I used cell editing template on the ag-grid site to override init method and inserted text input element with disabled style. It worked and rows I wanted not to edit became disable. But strange thing is every time the last cell in the disable row still on the edit mode. When I debug it did goes through the init method but still its rendering with the default out of the box rendering. Do you have any idea why that is happening. If not is this a bug in the ag-grid.

Comment: Following is my override init method.

this.childIndex = params.node.childIndex;
 if (params.node.childIndex == 0 || params.node.childIndex == 2) {
   params.api.stopEditing();
   this.eInput = document.createElement('input');
   this.eInput.value = params.value;
   this.eInput.style.disabled = "disabled"}
  else {
   this.focusAfterAttached = params.cellStartedEdit;
   this.eInput = document.createElement('input');
   this.eInput.style.width = '100%';
   this.eInput.style.height = '100%';
   this.eInput.value = isCharNumeric(params.charPress) ? params.charPress : params.value;}

Comment: If you still have `editable: true` in your column params, then remove it. Otherwise, it might be a bug that you could log on their [github page](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues). Or if you could reproduce your schema in a jsfiddle or plnkr then we might be able to help further

Comment: The solution i'm building is have some rows which user needs to enter values and some rows users can't edit those. I managed to make rows disable by overriding the method NumericCellEditor.prototype.isCancelBeforeStart and return true for the rows which I need to disable.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than setting `editable: true` you can set `editable` based on the data:

`editable: params => params.data.active === true`.

Hope that helps.